"There having been no rain for a long time, the fields are all dried up" Why is "there having"?
Is this sentence correct? if it is, why they use "having" here.

"having" forms the perfect aspect.  The sentence has an introductory participle phrase, but this uses the perfect, so is  "having been"
The meaning could be paraphrased with two clauses:  "There has been no rain (and so) The fields are dry"
